# Jenkins advanced dropdown parameters

Tags: jenkins, parameters, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way to make some parameters of a Jenkins Job in a dropdown like Advanced. Basically you have some parameters that are common, but some that are more sensitive and I want to hid those under an Advanced section. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Active Choice Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) will help you to achieve the scenario you mentioned.

There is example mentioned in the plugin documentation which can help you to implement the same.

Comment: I used https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameter-separator/ instead. But I appreciate your answer.

Comment: Thanks to you also. I was not aware of this plugin. I used it today in my pipeline.

Comment: Do you know a way to use Active Choice Parameter with rest api? idk what to write in that groovy script.